# MySql - Append string to particular position in list

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a column in my table that is a list of strings, how do I append a new entry into the list in the table (for all rows) after a particular item in the list?

```
for example: 
apple, orange, peach, banana,....
```

So here let's say I want to append `lemon` after the entry `peach` into every row. I know for a fact that the entry 'peach' occur in every row and it occurs only once (positioning of peach in the list might differ and occurrence of other items in the list may vary). Thanks in advance!

I tried (but didn't work)

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
concat (COLUMN_NAME, 'lemon') 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%peach,%';
```

Comment: Should `apple, peach, orange` result in `apple, peach, lemon, orange` or `apple, peach, orange, lemon`? (or something else for that matter :) )

Comment: Apple, orange, peach, lemon, banana,...

Comment: you mean `REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'peach,','peach, lemon,')`

Comment: No I tried both concat and replace

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
set COLUMN_NAME= replace(COLUMN_NAME, 'peach','peach,lemon') 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%peach,%';
```

Comment: Let us hope, duplicates won't exist.

Comment: No there are no duplicates of peach in the list in any row. I tried doing it for one particular row (to verify) and it get the same data truncation warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
create table test(test VARCHAR(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)

INSERT INTO test VALUES('apple, orange, peach, banana,....');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM test;
+-----------------------------------+
| test                              |
+-----------------------------------+
| apple, orange, peach, banana,.... |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE test SET test = REPLACE(test,'peach,','peach,lemon,') WHERE test like '%peach,%';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM test;
+-----------------------------------------+
| test                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
| apple, orange, peach,lemon, banana,.... |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately it didn't work and I get the warning "Data truncated for column COLUMN_NAME at row 1" with warning code 1265

Comment: @crazyim5 Then your field is defined as too short. The warning will happen when you - for example - define a field as `VARCHAR(5)` and try to insert 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

If the string `'peach'` does not appear as part of any other value in the "list" (that is, there aren't for example, any occurrences of terms in the list like `'impeach'` or `'peachtree'`, then you could use the `REPLACE` string function to find occurrences of `'peach'` and replace it with `'peach,lemon'`

For example:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycol = REPLACE(mycol, 'peach', 'peach,lemon')
```

In the more general case, you might not have the guarantee that `'peach'` was not part of some other term in the list, the expression to do that would be more complicated.

Comment: That's a good catch. Fortunately there is no impeach or any other substring version of peach in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
update tblname
set clm_name= replace(clm_name,'peach','peach,lemon') 
where clm_name like '%peach%';
```